# how to change button tag's text on ajax's success

Tags: django, jquery

Actually i know how to do this. But something is different here. There are many posts in index page. and every post located in `<li>` tags. And i have voting system for each posts.

```
<ul>

  <li class="class_li" data-id="this_posts_id">
   <a href="#" class="btn">Vote Up</a> <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" 
   data-toggle="dropdown">
     <span class="vote"> CURRENT VOTE </span>
      <span class="caret"></span> </button>
      </li>

      <li class="class_li" data-id="this_posts_id">
            <!-- another <li> for other posts with same tags and class names -->
      </li>
       <li class="class_li" data-id="this_posts_id">
            <!-- another <li> for other posts with same tags and class names -->
      </li>
</ul>
```

And my jquery code:

```
$('a.btn').click( function(){
        var post_id = $(this).closest('li').data('id');
        var vote = 1;
        var ajaxOpt = {
            type: 'post',
            url: '/content/vote/',
            data: {
                'vote': vote,
                'post_id': post_id,
                },
            success: function(data){
                $(this).find('.vote').text(data.vote_new); // this does not work!

                },
            error: function(){
                console.log('error :[');
                }
        };
        $.ajax(ajaxOpt);

    })
```

I tried `closest()` `parent()` and `find()`. All the same. Once i make it work. but that time all the post's vote values changed. Not ONLY in `<li>` tag's borders one.

I am stuck. Everything looks true. But something is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider starting a JSFiddle so we can fork and tinker with what you've already got.

Comment: `data.vote_new`...where is this defined?

Comment: @JeromyFrench in my view. Django. actually there is  {{ post.vote }} where written VOTE. that part works. after i refresh the page new vote number appears. but it should be without refres.

Comment: Since it appears each `<li>` has a unique ID based on this_posts_id why not give the vote element an ID too (`id="vote1", id="vote2" etc). You're sending post_id to the server, so have the server send it back and then `$('#vote'+data.post_id).text(data.vote_new);`

Comment: and if I understand you and the code, $(this) will be the `a` getting clicked...so you want the child element of `a`'s *siblings*: `$(this).siblings('button').find('.vote')...`

Comment: @AndyLastname you are what a great man :) it worked. but i didnt send post id with json from server. i already have post.id in template. just used it.

Comment: @JeromyFrench siblings didn't work man :/ but thank you again.

Comment: Is it possible to have `/content/vote/` return only the text you want to display: `<html><head>...</head><body><span id="the_answer">231</span></body></html>`, then just do `$(this).siblings('button').find('.vote').load('/content/vote/ #the_answer', {data})` ?

Comment: Just a final thought on this - for anyone else who comes across it: If you find yourself using jquery's find() or closest() etc functions then consider giving page elements their own unique ID.  Because if you change the HTML layout then your javascript will have to be changed to reflect that. Whereas a straight $('#element'+id);` is much less susceptible to HTML being altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the use of `$(this)` in the `success` callback. It is **not** the button, which is what your code is expecting. So you need to alter the code capture the reference outside of the `success` callback.

So below is the modified code:

- create a local variable for the button (`$this`)
- use `sibling()` and `find()` to get to the correct vote element

  ```
  $('a.btn').click( function(){

      //This will be the button - maybe call it $button if that's clearer
      var $this = $(this);

      var post_id = $(this).closest('li').data('id');
      var vote = 1;
      var ajaxOpt = {
          type: 'post',
          url: '/content/vote/',
          data: {
              'vote': vote,
              'post_id': post_id,
              },
          success: function(data){

              //This now works! :)
              $this.siblings('button').find('.vote').text(data.vote_new); 

              },
          error: function(){
              console.log('error :[');
              }
      };
      $.ajax(ajaxOpt);

  });
  ```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8NMR/3/)** showing the concept using your scenario.